# Расстановка знаков препинания при прямой речи

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

Интересует расстановка знаков препинания в следующем предложении:

**Тебя наверное интересует вопрос зачем мы хотим отправить тебя в Молино поинтересовался Антон**

Answer (score 1):

1. Для выделения прямой речи употребляются тире или кавычки:
   1.1. Если прямая речь начинается с абзаца, то перед началом ее ставится тире.
   1.2. Если прямая речь идет в строку, без абзаца, то перед началом и в конце ее ставятся кавычки.
2. "Слова автора"(предложение, стоящее при прямой речи и указывающее, кому она принадлежит) в Вашем предложении следуют за прямой речью. В этом случае после прямой речи ставится знак вопросительный, или восклицательный, или многоточие, или запятая (вместо точки), а за этим знаком — тире.
   [**Знаки при прямой речи**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/164-znapr)
3. *Наверное* — вводное слово, с двух сторон выделяется запятыми.
4. *...интересует вопрос* (какой именно?) — необходимо двоеточие(возможна и запятая).
5. Предложение вопросительное — необходим вопросительный знак.

***"Тебя, наверное, интересует вопрос: зачем мы хотим отправить тебя в Молино?" —  поинтересовался Антон.***
Или:
***—Тебя, наверное, интересует вопрос: зачем мы хотим отправить тебя в Молино? — поинтересовался Антон.***

Comment: Также возможны и другие варинаты расстановки знаков препинания: двоеточие после слова "вопрос" и убрать/поставить знак попроса; запятая после слова "вопрос" и убрать знак вопроса.

Comment: Ну, если разбираться _совсем обстоятельно_ , то мы дойдем до возможности постановки троеточия в конце предложения... Но! - ведь не об  _этих_ особенностях был вопрос! Я уж и так его попыталась - с точки зрения прямой речи - обсмотреть со всех сторон.

Comment: Спасибо за обстоятельный ответ. Меня, конечно, интересовала не все знаки препинания в этом предложении. В первую очередь, интересовал знак препинания после слова "вопрос"... Мне сегодня сказали что, в том месте, могут быть ещё одни кавычки...

Comment: Такое возможно, но тогда предложение будет иметь совсем другой вид(с РАЗНЫМИ кавычками). Как пример. "Тебя, наверное, интересует вопрос Ивана: «Зачем мы хотим отправить тебя в Молино?»" — поинтересовался Антон. Но Вы ведь НЕ ОБ ЭТОМ спрашивали!

Comment: Согласен с Риммой, в исходном тексте кавычки после слова "вопрос" неуместны. Можно, конечно, изменить предложение так, чтобы стало возможным поставить кавычки внутри кавычек, но это уже другой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

После "вопрос" запятая, дальше следует придаточное определительное.

"Тебя, наверное, интересует вопрос Ивана, зачем мы хотим отправить тебя в Молино?", — поинтересовался Антон.

Comment: Кто ж вас отминусил-то... Поправлю.  Хотя ответ и не самый развернутый, не настолько же он плох,, чтобы новичка минусовать...

Answer (score 0):

"Тебя, наверное, интересует вопрос Ивана: «Зачем мы хотим отправить тебя в Молино?»", — поинтересовался Антон.

Здесь после прямой речи, которая не заканчивается знаком вопроса, а кавычками, нужна запятая.

Если бы было

«Зачем мы хотим отправить тебя в Молино?» — поинтересовался Антон.

то не нужна была бы запятая после прямой речи, которая заканчивается знаком вопроса.

Comment: "Зачем мы хотим отправить **тебя** в Молино?" - это не слова Ивана. Как следует из контекста, Иван спросил: "Зачем мы хотим отправить **имярек** в Молино?". Неверно оформлять вопрос Ивана как прямую речь.